# How to define some constructors as for not-constant objects only?

Tags: c++, constants, compile-time

Having a following class:

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo() : m_data{std::nullopt} {} // this is fine (not having m_data set), 
                                  // but only at the beginnig of objects lifetime
  Foo(Bar data) : m_data{data} {}

  void setData(Bar newData);
  Bar getData() const;

  void doJob() const; // requires m_data to be set (not std::nullopt)
  void doOtherJob() const; // does not require m_data to be set.
  /*...*/

private:
  std::optional<Bar> m_data;
```

At the beginnig, there is a possibility of having `m_data` not set, but only to the point of first `setData()` call, then `m_data` will never ever go back to being empty (`std::nullopt`)

My question is, can I somehow tell the compiler to never allow constructing objects of type `Foo` with the first constructor (default one: `Foo()`) if those objects are marked as `const`
so that there will be no chance for this type of code:

```
const Foo x;           // without const totally fine
// x.setData( Bar{} ); // but with it, setData cannot be called
x.doJob();             // which makes that call a 100% throw error
                       // and in general, whole object is less usefull now
                       // because it is constructed only partially, 
                       // and cannot be finished
```

to pass compilation stage?

Final efect should look like this:

```
Bar data = getSomeData();

Foo a;             // fine
Foo b{data};       // fine
const Foo c;       // error, this type will never be usefull / is artificially limited, 
                   // no logical reason to make it const
const Foo d{data}; // fine
```

Is there any way to get at compile time information about `const'ness` of a given new object (in objects class construction code or definition), so that I could use SFINAE or something else to split, distinguish diffrent construction routines for `const` and `not-const` objects?

I want it to be done at compile-time.

It would be nice to be able to just write something like:

```
class Foo{
public:
                                    // both can still mutate everything
  Foo() { /*...*/ }                 // but this one cant be called by const objects            
  Foo(Bar data) const { /*...*/ }   // and this one can
};
```

which would not try to make `this` pointer `const Foo*` but only pretend like it, so `const` objects could not call this first "method", but that is not allowed to what I know & checked up to this point.

(type `Bar` cannot be set to some sort of default value, null value. It either is, or not, and I would like to keep it that way)

I also don't know why it is not possible to mark constructors with `const`, because then (in my opinion) there would be no problem with all those classes where objects can be constructed partially, but after still have to be fulfilled completely in order to work properly or work in its potential.

I couldn't find any other programmer with same issue so I bringed up extended code sample to check is it really a problem (having different approach for creation of `const` objects) or do I just simply do things in a wrong way. Is there any design pattern, style of programming, etc. that I'm missing and which makes those problems not existing?

I know that at `run-time` there is no difference between `const` and `not-const` objects but that's not the point. I believe this problem can be solved at `compile-time`, i just don't know how to tell a compiler what I have in mind.

**Edit**:
making an object with `Foo()` is useful (using only a part of its functionality), but only if later it will do its main job which requires `m_data`.

Comment: sounds to me like you want instances of the same class to have different behaviour, so maybe better make it two classes. On the other hand, why is there a defualt constructor, if the field has to be set for the object to be in a valid state? Its the job of the constructor to construct a valid object, it shouldnt be needed to call member functions (in the right order) for the instance to be usable

Comment: Why not just disallow `Foo() : m_data{std::nullopt} {}` completely? What is the point of such constructor if you can't use this class anyway before setData and others? Your `optional` field doesn't make much sense currently. You could as well "move it out" to `optional<Foo>` where you'd use your old constructor.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this is impossible.

Comment: to answer your question literally: It is not possible. Its more or less the same situation as when you return a value from a method `Foo foo();`, the only way for the method to control whether the returned value is mutable or not is to return a mutable/immutable type

Comment: Because objects created with `Foo()` are still usable, have other useful "jobs" (same with those that are `const`). They can be constructed like that because sometimes there is no `Bar data` when object is being created but is still needed. I have that variant (`Foo()`) also for convenience, code looks clearier and better with it. It is just that additional opportunity to write error code shown above that bothering me. Splitting up class `Foo` into two separate ones would seem to be artificial, just to avoid that problem.

Comment: I edited my question so that it not misleading right now to thinking that `Foo()` is unnecessary (or object created by it)

Comment: Maybe change `void doJob() const;` to `void doJob(const Bar&) const;` might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to know in the constructor whether the object will be const or non-const. So, your desired functionality is not possible to implement. You have two options:

- Remove the default constructor. If `doJob` is an error for a default constructed object, then why not dis-allow such invalid state?
- Accept the fact that `const Foo c;` is useless, but the compiler will not tell the programmer. The programmer should find this out quite soon if they test the code that they write. The uselessness should also become quite clear from the documentation of the class.

Comment: (Being curious) So does my opinion on `const` constructors (being able to mark them as such) make sense? I'm guessing that it could be a thing if only not all those complications that it would bring on in other scenarios but on the other hand, I don't see any of them, with proper implicit behavior even all those meta-template magician codes should still work same way right? Can someone pin-point me to one reason why this is not possible?

Comment: @KungFuJesus3 tbh I dont think its a good idea to have different behaviour based on constness (other than const correctness), you can always make a non-const copy of a const instance, so you'd need to forbid copying too, eventually you will end up with a non-mutable class (for which it does'nt matter if an instance is declared const or not, because it is immutable by design)